# set NSArray instance using reference in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I'm trying to set the values for NSArray using reference in Swift but can't seem to get it working.

```
var list = self.isFiltered ? self.filteredEventsList : self.eventsList
self.sortTableViewForEventName(&list)
```

Then:

```
private func sortTableViewForEventName(inout eventArray: NSArray) {

        let sortedEvents = eventArray.sortedArrayUsingComparator({ (firstEvent, secondEvent) in

            let firstEventName = (firstEvent as! Event).name
            let secondEventName = (secondEvent as! Event).name

            return firstEventName.compare(secondEventName)
        })

        eventArray = sortedEvents
    }
```

The change in eventArray does not reflect in eventsList or filteredEventsList, whichever may be applicable.

Comment: inout parameters should be used rarely. In this case it would be simpler for your function to return the sorted array.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please show us how to use it ... and why it is not working because of block ?

Comment: Also why use an `NSArray`? You should most probably be using a native Swift array instead.

Comment: Why are you using an `NSArray` here? why not just use a swift array? It makes filtering and sorting much easier too.

Comment: @Fogmeister how so? can you elaborate?

Comment: @Crazed'n'Dazed check my answer :D Shows you how much easier it becomes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a really good reason for using `inout` parameters, and in this case I don't think you have one.  You can simply have your function return the sorted array:

```
private func sortTableViewForEventName(eventArray: NSArray) -> NSArray {
    let sortedEvents = eventArray.sortedArrayUsingComparator({ (firstEvent, secondEvent) in

        let firstEventName = (firstEvent as! Event).name
        let secondEventName = (secondEvent as! Event).name

        return firstEventName.compare(secondEventName)
    })

    return sortedEvents
}
```

then you would say

```
var list = self.isFiltered ? self.filteredEventsList : self.eventsList
list = self.sortTableViewForEventName(list)
```

But, unless you have a good reason for using `NSArray`, you can just use a Swift array and gain type awareness/safety and more concise sorting:

```
private func sortTableViewForEventName(eventArray: [Event]) -> [Event] {
    let sortedEvents = eventArray.sort {
        $0.name < $1.name
    }
    return sortedEvents
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier in this case to use a Swift array `[Event]` you can then sort and filter something like this...

```
private func sortedEventsByName(events: [Event]) -> [Event] {
    return events.sort {
        $0.name > $1.name
    }
}
```

What would be even simpler is to create an extension on `Event` like so...

```
extension Event: Comparable {}

func == (lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
    return lsh.name == rhs.name
}

func < (lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}
```

Then you can just use sort like this...

```
let sortedEvents = events.sort(<)
```

and

```
let filteredEvents = events.filter {
    $0.name == someFilterName
}
```

Comment: very nice answer , as i am learning swift so please  can you explain what is extension Event: Comparable {} ?

Comment: @MikeAlter Comparable is a protocol defined in swift that allows you to compare items of the same type. It requires the two methods == and <. The sort method in swift can be run on any homogeneous collection type that has Comparable elements. The extension here is just telling Swift that Event is now a comparable type.

Answer (score 0):

What you give to `sortTableViewForEventName` is a reference to `list`, and `NSArray` is immutable, so the only thing you modify is the local variable `list`.

you might try this :

```
var list = self.isFiltered ? self.filteredEventsList : self.eventsList
self.sortTableViewForEventName(&list)
if self.isFiltered {
  self.filteredEventsList = list
} else {
  self.eventsList = list
}
```

or this (not sure if it works) :

```
self.sortTableViewForEventName(self.isFiltered ? &self.filteredEventsList : &self.eventsList)
```

or make filteredEventsList and eventsList NSMutableArray, but it's probably not a good idea, because it would break encapsulation.